# repeat fadein/fadeout in custom jquery function, avoiding interval or timeout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am new to jQuery and I can't seem to figure out how to make my code repeat the same tasks over.

What I'm trying to do is this:

- I select random strings from a set of different arrays
- using a custom jquery function, I fade several of these textbits in and out at random spots on the
  screen, each at slightly different times (text-overlap is ok). I'm also varying the font size.
- Basically, I would like to repeat the process forever, i.e. select a new set of random
  strings from the same arrays, fade them in and out in random
  positions

My question(s):

1. Can I repeat the process avoiding setInterval and setTimeout, and if so, how?

If you have an extra minute, I'd also appreciate help with the following:

2. How can I adjust my positions (posx and posy) so that the text does not extend beyond the screen (i.e. the user can see it without scrolling)?
3. Are there any issues with the code that I should be aware off? Where can I improve it?

My html:

```
    <span id="one"></span>
    <span id="two"></span>
    <span id="three"></span>
    <span id="four"></span>
    <span id="five"></span>
```

My script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var cT1 = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Strawberries", "Blueberries", "Bananas"];
var cT2 = ["Maccaroni", "Tortellini", "Spaghetti", "Fettucine", "Tangliatelle"];
var cT3 = ["New York", "Paris", "Rome", "Berlin", "London"];
var cT4 = ["Labrador", "Coonhound", "Beagel", "Bernese Mountaindog", "Pittbull"];
var cT5 = ["Triceratops", "Stegosaurus", "Tyrannosaurus Rex", "Brachiosaurus", "Ankilosaurus"];

jQuery.fn.extend({
customFunction : function (cT, predelay, fadeintime, delaytime, fadeouttime, maxSize, minSize){     

var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() -$(this).height())).toFixed();
var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - $(this).width())).toFixed();
var emptytime = predelay + fadeintime + delaytime + fadeouttime;

var fader = $(this)
.hide()
.text(cT[Math.floor(Math.random()*cT.length)])
.delay(predelay).fadeIn(fadeintime)
.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'font-size': (Math.random()*maxSize+minSize)+'px'
    })
.delay(delaytime)
.fadeOut(fadeouttime);

setTimeout(function(){$(this).empty();},emptytime);

return fader; 
}
});

$('#one').customFunction(cT1, 0, 4000, 2000, 4000, 40, 15);
$('#two').customFunction(cT2, 2000, 3000, 5000, 3000, 50, 20);
$('#three').customFunction(cT3, 4000, 4000, 1000, 4000, 60, 25);
$('#four').customFunction(cT4, 500, 3000, 1000, 3000, 45, 20);
$('#five').customFunction(cT5, 5000, 4000, 2000, 4000, 55, 30);
});
```

Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I know you've tagged this for jQuery/JS, but have you considered GSAP? Their timelines are SUPER easy to chain, and very easy to make infinitely repeating. Lots of functionality built-in, and it's super fast. Just figured I'd throw that in the ring as well.